# Laravel Eloquent returns QueryException, Base table or view not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I implemented laravel eloquent to retrieve data from database (I use mysql). I had performed migration to create table 'r_prereportagen' with migration file '2015_09_04_200539_create_pre_reportagens_table.php'. A file named pre_reportagen.php was appeared in /app directory, I used the class pre_reportagen defined in pre_reportagen.php and my application ends up with error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'appumrohsurabaya.pre_reportagens' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `pre_reportagens`). I've examined my database, and I was sure that my table 'r_prereportagen' was there. Is anyone find the mistakes?

Comment: You mentioned that there's `r_prereportagen` table but it clearly says that it cant find `pre_reportagens` ?

Comment: Maybe it's a naming convention issue. In your model you have to explicitly specify the _protected $table "table-name'';_ property :)

Comment: I realized that naming convention is important. But thank you guys, I was able run my code by adding `protected $table = 'r_prereportagen';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are sure that `r_prereportagen` exists in your database, but eloqunt looking 'pre_reportagens' table. still if you want your table name as `r_prereportagen`
just overwrite the table name on your pre_reportagen.php files, just before `fillables` property

`protected $table = 'r_prereportagen';`

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent expects a table that is the plural of the model name. In your error it already states that it is looking for a table named appumrohsurabaya.pre_reportagens while you created the singular version (appumrohsurabaya.pre_reportagen, without the s).

So in your model, set the following code:

```
protected $table = "r_prereportagen"
```

Comment: Please mark one of the usefull answers as the final answer, so that in the future other users can easily find the correct answer.